# convert drop down list box to UL LI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list box here:

```
<select class="CountrySelectList" name="CountrySelectList" id="CountrySelectList" onchange="self.location='setlocale.aspx?returnURL=Default.aspx&amp;localesetting=' + document.getElementById('CountrySelectList').value" size="1">
    <option value="de-DE">Deutsch</option>
    <option selected="" value="en-US">English</option>
    <option value="fr-FR">Francais</option>
    <option value="it-IT">Italiano</option>
    <option value="es-ES">Español</option>
    <option value="pt-PT">Português</option>
    <option value="cs-CZ">Czech Republic</option>
    <option value="pl-PL">Polska</option>
    <option value="hu-HU">Hungary</option>
</select>
```

What is the best way to convert this to a bullet list so that i can display them in a row like this:(my example doesnt reflect the dd- but you get the idea)

I would like to use jquery or javascript?

```
UK | DE | CZ
```

Comment: Is there any reason you don't do this in the source code instead of dynamically on each page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baz is correct. It's not optimal, but maybe you don't have a choice?

```
var countryArr = [];
var $ul = $('<ul />');
countryArr = $('#CountrySelectList option').map(function() {
    return this.value
}).get();
$.each(countryArr, function() {
    $ul.append('<li>' + this.slice(3));
});
$('body').append($ul);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uZRqM/)**

Comment: You have provided me with an answer. But everyone says i should hard code the markup.

Comment: @sp-1986 While technically possible, it is not advised if you can just change the markup.

Comment: Agreed, definitely hard code the markup and avoid the performance hit.

Comment: I have modded your script slightly and included it in your answer. It will help other people.

Answer (score 1):

*You should not do this.* Your Javascript would run on every page load, unnecessarily wasting resources.

It does not take much time to write the new markup, **a list of links** that you can easily style with CSS to look like what you need. When you need a list of links in your page, why would you have a form element in your markup?

```
<ul id="CountrySelectList" class="CountrySelectList">
    <li>
         <a href="setlocale.aspx?returnURL=Default.aspx&amp;localesetting=de-DE">DE</a>
    </li>
    <li>
         <a class="selected" href="setlocale.aspx?returnURL=Default.aspx&amp;localesetting=en-US">US</a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

[Here is a simple jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aKK7D/1/)

Comment: You are right i could just hard code this in the skin or topic page.